# What's an alternative term for "nip off to"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am thinking of an alternate way of saying

> I [nip off] to the local store with my dog every day.

The alternative should include a replacement for the verb ‘[nip off to](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/nip_1?q=nip)’ and give the meaning of going somewhere discreetly.

Comment: "I scoot off to the local store every day, after lunch."

Comment: For my fellow confused Americans: apparently [this sense of *nip*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/nip_1?q=nip) is only found in British English.

Comment: To me, *nip off* is about speed - the discreetness arises because a short absence is less likely to be noticed.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest "sneak off":

> leave furtively and stealthily
> synonyms: slip away, sneak away, sneak out, steal away
> — [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sneak%20off)

Example in use:

> About two hours before our last Holiday Cocktail Party my husband snuck off to the store and came back with a big bag of craft supplies — [comment on *Toby’s Genius Way of Making Friends*](https://cupofjo.com/2022/08/08/how-to-make-friends-as-adult/)

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it is somewhat rare for discretion to be explicitly included in expressions of the kind that you are looking for. Instead, any discretion is left as an implication by means of the casual, easygoing, and somewhat unplanned nuance of the phrases. Here are two options that might, nevertheless, meet your needs.

["Pop into"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pop-in-into) or "pop by" might meet your needs.

> pop in/into (somewhere)
> phrasal verb with pop verb
> to visit briefly:
> *"Why don’t you pop in and see us this afternoon?"*
> If you pop into a place, you visit there briefly, usually for some purpose:
> *"All I have to do on the way home is pop into the drugstore."*

["Drop by"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop-by-in) or "drop in" is similar

> drop by/in
> phrasal verb with drop verb
> to visit someone:
> *"I dropped in on George on my way home from school."
>
> "Drop by and pick up that book sometime."*

Although the above definition indicates "to visit *someone*", it is not strictly necessary that the target be a specific person. It can certainly be used in reference to a place, like a supermarket or a book store (as implied in the second example).

Answer (score 1):

*Nip off to* expresses speed, not discreetness (other than the fact that you might want to move fast so as to go undetected):

> **nip** *verb<sup>1</sup>*
> **III.** Senses relating to snatching, seizing, or moving quickly.
> **III.9.a.** *intransitive*. *colloquial* (chiefly *British*). To move rapidly or nimbly; to go quickly; to make a brief excursion. Usually
> with *down*, *in*, *into*, *out*, etc. Also (in extended use, esp.
> with *in*): to take rapid action.
> <sub>[sample]</sub>
> <sub>**1998**   Hey our Antony, nip down to the offie and get us some ciggies.</sub>

If you need speed and discreetness, try *slip off to*:

> **slip** *verb<sup>1</sup>*
> **I.i.2.** To pass or go lightly or quietly; to move quickly and softly, without attracting notice; to glide or steal. Used with
> various adverbs and prepositions.
>  <sup>In some cases the prominent
> idea is that of escape; more usually it is that of quick, easy
> motion.</sup>
> **I.i.2.a.** With *away*, *off*, *out*; *from*, *out of*.
> <sub>[sample]</sub>
> <sub>**1878**   So I came down stairs without any noise and slipped out.</sub>

If you just need discreetness, how about *slink off to*?

> **slink** *verb*
> **1.a.** *intransitive.* Of persons or animals: To move, go, walk, etc. in a quiet, stealthy, or sneaking manner. Usually const. with
> prepositions and adverbs.
>  <sub>[sample]</sub>
> <sub>**1879**   He had to slink
> into Thessalonica incognito, and by night.</sub>

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No exact replacement but you might consider

- “step away to” [conveys very brief absence]
- “peace out to” [conveys abandoning the current task utterly]
- “slip away to” [conveys unobtrusive motion]
- “dip out to” [conveys unserious intent]